Schrödinger's cat ++
I encountered something new a few days ago which I thought I'd pass on..
I think most of you will be aware of Schrödinger's cat (but for those that don't):
The idea is that at the quantum level reality begins acting strangely and can create something called an 'observers paradox' where the observer 'makes' reality through the simple act of observation.
Schrödinger has a cat in a sealed box which could be alive or dead, he won't know until he opens the box. The cat is in a state of being both alive and dead at the same time until Schrödinger checks to see.
Of course the interesting thing here is exactly which or whose reality changes when Schrödinger opens the box to find the cat alive and well (or you actually measure which slit the photon went through etc, to be more accurate)
Was it the cat's reality that changed, or Schrödinger's?
Here's the new (to me at least) twist.
What if the room that Schrödinger is in is itself a box just like the cat's?
When Schrödinger opens the box he sees the cat is dead, but to people outside his laboratory don't know yet until, they open his door and ask.
And what if they're in a box, and so ad-infinitum.
In other words, is there such a thing as reality itself.
Now I know that this is something you all grapple with on a daily basis using other thought experiments than this one, but I'd like to know what extended analysis there is of this.
To frame it as a question: Does this thought experiment (many boxes in other boxes) show that reality CANNOT exist?

The principle behind Schrodinger's Cat is based on the fact that, until observed, the cat is genuinely both dead and alive simultaneously since its death is predicated on a 'quantum' event (of course this seems ridiculous and extremely counterintuitive - welcome to quantum mechanics!)

Once it is observed by one person, the outcome is deterministic and whether or not other people view the event or the person who viewed the event is irrelevant. The important point that many miss when it comes to Schrodinger's Cat is that it is a description of a phenomenon in quantum mechanics. Without further analysis, it means nothing from a philosophical perspective

I think there are Idealists who'd argue differently.

Some of us argue that by observing the observer merely falls into the same quantum superposition until they are in turn observed.

There is only one reality under QM. Even in the many worlds interpretation, each world occurs, but reality is one and the same. In the “traditional” interpretation, the cat is neither dead nor alive before observation.

@Syed I know that it's an analogy. Quantum Uncertainty doesn't apply 'typically' on a macro scale. The analogy isn't meant to hold to cat's in boxes scale.
But.. I think even a lot of physicists are quite perturbed by this.

I mean.. if quantum uncertainty is uncertain 'all the way down' then what is the nature of reality?

I'm not sure of the proper physics term for the interpretation, but there is no weirdness at all if one considers a quantum state to represent what is known about the subject (cat or anything) rather than any deeper reality about it.

This is Winger's Friend.

I'm reminded of Bell's Theorem that posits we cannot have local realism - either you have realism or locality but not both. Neither options are intuitive.

The quantum world itself is deterministic with highest tick rate (smallest wavelength), it's just our world as observer that unable to capture fully what happened inside the box. So, sampling with opening the box all we can do.

You don't need nested boxes for your thought experiment: The original one would do if you place yourself in it. Do you  experience "reality"?

As an aside, the nested boxes idea is a good model for the light cone expanding: The outer reaches cannot know anything about the inner ones before light from the inner ones reaches them (i.e., the boxes are opened). We are all entangled, after the connection.

Once it is observed by one person, the outcome is deterministic and whether or not other people view the event or the person who viewed the event is irrelevant. @FD_bfa What is special about humans to determine outcome? Would a dog be an observer too? Can the cat itself observe and determine the outcome? Human brains are complex, but there isn't a special "observer chip" that makes us able to 'collapse' the universe - but another living organism couldn't.

@KristianBerry
He may have been one of the physicists in the youtube video I watched on this subject (no, I didn't find this in an academic paper :) )
I think the concept of quantum uncertainty never truly resolving is worrying, especially to those who understand the subject properly! I'll find and read the paper thanks.

@Annika Yes I think that's the core it

This is called "Wigner's friend paradox"

The idea you raise is an old one, which I think is usually attributed to Eugene Wigner (who, incidentally, had some bizarre ideas not withstanding the fact that he was an ace theoretical physicist). However, you are barking, or should that be meowing, up the wrong tree. The whole point of Schrödinger's thought experiment, as far as its inventor was concerned, was to prove how the then current interpretation of quantum mechanics led to idiotic conclusions when applied to macroscopic objects. Chaining a series of SC experiments like a set of Russian dolls simply replicates the idiocy- it doesn't invalidate the concept of reality. But if I'm wrong, please feel free to come to my farm, borrow a clutch of my finest pedigree sows and fly them to any destination of your choosing.

This pretty much nails it. The Schrodinger's Cat thing has been blown wildly out of proportion by popular culture and most people misinterpret what it's actually trying to convey.

"Although originally a critique on the Copenhagen interpretation, Schrödinger's seemingly paradoxical thought experiment became part of the foundation of quantum mechanics." It is, so to speak, the Yankee Doodle of the Copenhagen gang. Dismissing the question on that basis is disingenuous.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica It's not foundational at all, since it's obviously not a real experiment. In reality, a cat is just as much of an observer as anyone else: it has eyes to see, ears to ear and a nose to smell. It will certainly notice the change, if it gets poisoned and terminally ill. Let us not import into QM the pre-darwinian idea that human beings are worlds apart from other animals.

@Olivier5 What I wanted to say is that the Schrödinger's Cat thought experiment was originally meant to dismiss the Copenhagen interpretation by showing the absurdity of its consequences. The "Copenhagians" replied "indeed, this is exactly how it works!" though. Therefore, dismissing the thought experiment as "idiocy" dismisses Bohr, Heisenberg and Born. Doing that without further discussion is unconvincing.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica I agree. I was just proposing that the Schrödinger's Cat thought experiment FAILED to show the absurdity of the Copenhagen interpretation because the cat itself can be seen as an observer of its own life. IMO that's what Bohr and co. should have answered.  Not that I subscribe to the  Copenhagen interpretation myself, but I don't believe that this particular thought experiment proves anything.

Chaining the series of experiments has a separate value: in Copenhagen interpretation after opening the box, the wavefonction gets collapsed. But according to the observer outside the laboratory it has not collapsed yet. So, the wavefunction is both collapsed and not. But this cannot be the case in  Copenhagen interpretation. So, one of the observers can collapse the wavefunction, while the other one cannot, or the Copenhagen interpretation is wrong.

I agree with @Peter-ReinstateMonica. We don't really care about why Schrödinger invented this "paradox": it is still an open problem to make sense of what is really happening (see Philomath's answer).

@Plop it is still an open question- agreed. The nonsense, however, pedalled by the pop-science brigade, is the assumption that the cat is alive and dead, in the everyday sense, until the box is opened.

@Olivier5 But if the cat is an observer, what isn't an observer? If having an eye makes you an observer, shouldn't having photoreceptors be enough. But if that's true, isn't any light-sensitive molecule an observer? And by extension any light-sensing atom? And yet, atoms have been demonstrated to be able to exist in a superposition of excited and non-excited states. At that point you have arrived back at the original question: Where do you draw the line between the quantum realm and "our" reality?

@fgp I agree that it would be important for Copenhagians to define the concept of "observer". Pending such a definition, they don't know what they talk of.

Be assured: this is reality.
The thought experiment illustrates quantum decoherence where quantum coherence (superposition, quantum entanglement) breaks down and quantum systems convert to classical systems. The precise mechanism is an open problem in physics and hence subject to interpretation. However, the early view that an observer was essential for dechorence is no longer held to be true. Entanglement of the quantum system with the environment and temperature seem to be determining factors.
Classical systems, the real world of table and chairs, can be seen as locally emergent, but they no longer play a fundamental role in physics. The underlying reality can be represented by a universal wave function, but locally (like when standing in line in the supermarket) this decoheres to everyday classical physics regardless whether you are in Copenhagen or in one of the many worlds...
Ironically, Schrödinger's cat experiment was original meant as a critique on the Copenhagen interpretation to show the folly of the idea.

Interestingly, the experiment description is a fallacy. What QM does is manipulating mathematical objects representing a distribution of physical possible properties. It's a tool to help compute probabilities, not to explain or predict the behavior of a single quantum object.
When the experiment tries to link the cat's live to the "abstract" Quantum object, it's making an error. In the usual description, the object used is the probability of some atom to disintegrate. It's not the atom, it's not the beta or alpha particle, it's not the switch/detector that would trigger the poison and kill the cat. It's an abstract object that encodes all the probability of the atom/beta/switch/poison/cat state.
You can pack as many stuff as you want in that object, it doesn't make it real (for whatever definition of reality), since the start of the chain isn't real.
It's exactly like when you buy a lottery ticket and start dreaming of all the marvelous stuff you'll buy with the prize. This doesn't make the owning of the prize (or the stuffs) real, it's only a probability. Once the lottery is drawn, it becomes a fact, all probabilities chains collapse for the million players who have lost and for the one who's won.
You could also see it like a credit in a bank, but for a thought chain. You can use that virtual money as tool to gain some other product or potentially another credit. But until all the chain realize, it's nothing more than a dream or an algorithm. If any link in the chain is not a real, concrete object, then the whole chain is only an abstract object.
We are so used to manipulate tools and models of objects we don't make the distinction anymore between the model and the object.
There is nothing in the Schrödinger experiment that's different from this. He's linking a model of some mathematical function to a model of a cat and the model of an observer. He doesn't make it real.
If some dude were to replicate the experiment in his reality, he wouldn't prove the model, since you can't prove the mathematical function's model is actually reality. In his experiment, the actual atom will or will not disintegrate and the cat will or will not die. It's only if he replicated the experiment sufficiently often that he could prove that the cat's life is following the statistics of the atom disintegration (minus the efficiency of the detector and the resilience of the cat to the poison).
Once he'd have proved it, and set up a new similar experiment, without observing the cat vital signs, he'd be able to confirm that the probability of the cat being alive is following the probability of the atom's disintegration.
Unlike what is usually said, the cat isn't alive or dead (or both at the same time). The cat is either alive or dead, yet the observer hasn't made the observation yet so the chain of thought hasn't collapsed yet. The observer however, can describe, with a quantum object, the wave function of the cat and "collapse" the wave function when he's actually doing the observation (which collapses of the chain of functions describing the complete system).
If a timer was added in the box that would have reset when the cat plays with some toy in the box, he could even know precisely when the atom disintegrated. And the distribution for that time would follow the quantum model of the atom disintegration very precisely, that's the beauty of the QM, you can actually use the tools to predict the distribution of a linked state, even if not a particle or a quantum object.

The experiment you described is known as Wigner's friend paradox.
There are multiple sci-pop links on this:

https://www.informationphilosopher.com/solutions/experiments/wigners_friend/
https://www.quantumfoundations.org/wigners-friend-thought-experiment.html
https://www.popularmechanics.com/science/a36633457/wigners-friend-paradox/

To answer your quection, no. The explanation of your experiment depends on what quantum interpretation you choose.

Schroedinger illustrates by his thought experiment that the transition from the assumed indeterminism on the quantum level to determinism on the usual scale is a mysterious phenomenon, not understood by quantum mechanics.

The current explanation of the transition is the mechanism of
decoherence: On the quantum level the decay of a radiactive atom is
described by a wavefunction psi. Like every wavefunction, also psi
has the capability that it interferes with itself due to its
well-defined phase – as long as the wave is coherent.
But the interaction with the environment, e.g., the cat itself and
the glass of the container, destroys the coherence and eliminates
the capability to interfere with itself. It is no longer a
superposition of different states.
If the atom decays, then within
a short time the capability of interference is lost and the wave
function of the composite system atom + cat settles into the
definite state of the cat being dead.
Adding further container does
not alter the definite result within the first container. They are
irrelevant for further analysis.

I recommend the following video by Sabine Hossenfelder; decoherence
starts at about 4.34 min. Hossenfelder adds a series of later
experiments.  Emphasizing that the interpretation of Schroedinger’s
cat is still an object of subtle scientific research.
She ends with the historical fact that Schroedinger himself had no
cat at all but a dog whose name is well-known :-)



That's somewhat of an incomplete narration of Schrödinger's Cat. You're not just placing a cat in a box and don't know whether it's still alive.
The problem is rather that it is an attempt to make present potential consequences of the Copenhagen interpretation of Quantum Mechanics, which asserts that the inability to predict Quantum Experiments beyond probability of outcomes, is not a problem of the incompleteness of the theory which isn't (yet) able to actually measure the wave function, but that it's an expression of the indeterministic nature of Quantum Mechanics and that the wavefunction itself doesn't have to be real, beyond a mathematical device to help compute the probabilities.
So in simpler terms the quantum mechanic particle would be in a superposition of states or think of it as a blur of all the possible states until the observer interferes with the system. So idk like rolling dice until the observer makes them stop and reveal a particular face.
Now blurred particle states might not sound particularly alarming to a casual listener so Schrödinger made that more plastic:
What if you take an unstable atom who's decay is governed by a quantum states and build a contraption so that upon detecting the decay of the atom, a vial of poison is broken and kills everyone in the room. So the release of that poison would be the result of the quantum state. So in other words if the quantum state is blurred so is the release probability of the poison (that's actually a huge assumption whether you can entangle a quantum state to a macroscopic state, but for the sake of argument he does that).
Now if you place both the contraption and a cat in a box, both the quantum state and the poison as well as the poison and the cat's state would depend on the result of the decay or not decay and would thus be in a blurred state. Which in consequence means that the cat would be in a blurred state of "dead and alive"!
But a blurred state of "dead and alive" is inconceivable (not talking in between states or coma or whatnot, but  and the cat would be both a living creature and a dead object), though a real cat would presumably  not experience itself as dead and alive but either as alive or not at all (because it's dead). So he argued against naively accepting such a blurred state model.
So in a sense the original example already had features of what you describe. On top of that there is the "Wigner's friend" thought example, which seems to be precisely what you describe.
Where an observer observes an observer and where the two statements about the measurement contradict as one observer is linked to the experiment and the other isn't. Which according to Heisenbergian interpretation is a matter of where to apply the Heisenberg cut between the indeterministic quantum layer and the deterministic non-quantum layer.
Though likely both observers are far into the macroscopic world and while there are plenty of interpretations, the inexistence of reality doesn't seem to be among them.

That's great thought process and idea. So what, if it's not the first time it's mentioned in history. It wasn't Newton either who came up with the fresh idea of calculus.
I think this idea is perfectly sane and doesn't break the Schrodinger Cat or anything, nor is a misinterpretation . In fact, macro level decoherence has been very well explained with animations in this video.
It's a philosophy forum and one shouldn't be limited by what has been proven to be true. So it's totally ok to assume things to be true even if it's not been proved yet.
My Key Idea
I think universe exist in multiple realities, and the splitting of reality is happening continiously. When we say split, people think binary tree, but it's our dumb assumption. I think the data structure of split here is quantum in nature and not classical for obvious reasons. It's splitting and joining back at all the time leading to a quantum but sane reality.
Why it's not complete BS
Limits of current experiments:

All quantum experiments so far have been done of a limited number of quantum particles, not on trillions of quantum particles. And it's not known if the entanglement of so many particles evolves into more organized quantum shapes. Just like no one can ever wrap their head around Airplane Lift by blowing air out of their mouth for 1 second. How can we be sure about macroscopic quantum behaviour?

This is backed by the philosophical idea of "Feynman's Path Integral" for Macro objects:
If path of classical particles is actually a sum of their quantum paths, then why can't it be extended to macroscopic objects. Turns out, it's not just me who wonder this.
Reprojection of your experiment
Let me rephrase this experiment into a much simpler one let's say our life exist on the surface of sea, and opening a cat box release a color in the water. The color is localized and doesn't diffuse, until someone observe it. But when the observer observe the color, their own color offet to a new color, which is the function of the color released by the cat box. The said observation here is over simplified and binary. The cat is not just dead or alive. It's also whether the dead cat's eyes are red, or if alive cat is purring or not. So the new color of the observer also depends on what they noted about the cat, and not on some absolute reality of cat inside the box. What they observe in the box would be a function of their old color.
Possible intuition on macro Feynman's Path Integral
Let's forget about the internet, or tele communication for now and that any observation is possible without physical proximity. Now we can safely assume that there are much higher chances that observers closer to each other physically on the sea surface will change their color before observers further from each other. Let's say each observer have 100 colors. And only a subset change by observing their surroundings at a time. Do you think how the color of each observers change on the sea surface is random like white noise, or is there a pattern or waves. For some reason I'm unable to imagine a white noise here and there clearly are waves.
Answer to your question
Was it the cat's reality that changed, or Schrödinger's?

Even though dead cat is not an active observer, it's atoms are still observing. So reality will change for both because multiple realities exist. And it's totally possible that their realities will collapse back one day. Let's say all this was happening on an island, which was lavafied by a volcano the next day. Nobody ever finds out anything about Schrodinger or the cat ever till the end of the world, they only find ashes. And nobody can tell who died first (or are not interested in spending resources on it). Now the many world have collapsed back.

Reality cannot exist?

It can, surely if there are multiple realities, all set to collapse back to one reality at the right point in time, maybe momentarily, only to split again.

Closing Ideas
Moreover there's no reason why Copenhagen, Many world interpretation, Objective collapse theories have to be mutually exclusive. Water is liquid, but with the right conditions it freezes, change to snow. Our idea of reality doesn't need to be rigid. Our philosophy doesn't need to be bound by what has been proven or not proven by physics.
If physics at a later point discovers something and proves your opinion to be wrong, it will simply evolve, and your mind will adapt, just like physics itself. Your key ideas are not bound to physics thought and might not change even if your on-the-surface ideas are proven wrong.
With a many-world interpretation, I think philosophically, it mean that I have clones in other universes, that I don't have access to. But will I ever talk to these clones, will after I'm dead, all these clones converge to a single wave (soul) and share each other's experience? Will I come back with experience from all many-worlds I lived in? Maybe it's not about the observer,
it's about the bigger questions about me, my identity, my reality, who am I,.. that statistically speaking, will never get answered. Thus, it converges to either finding peace with the unknown, or reading real physics books keeping your philosophy in sync with latest physics. I prefer both.
Criticism is welcome

Apologies for late response:
"..surely if there are multiple realities, all set to collapse back to one reality"
I think the point is that there aren't 'multiple' realities, but an infinite (practically) amount. And so the wave function is just 'collapsing' forever with no actual resolution except to the local observer.

This is too long for a comment.
The question has at least four wrong premises:

where the observer 'makes' reality through the simple act of
observation

This is just bad physics popularization. Observers do not make any reality by observing things. One imprecise but more correct way to say what happens during a measurement would be that "something happens that make the observer only see a term of a superposition".

a cat in a sealed box which could be alive or dead

No, this is not what superposition is about. If I take your cat, go in a closed room with it and come back with a box, you could think the cat could be alive or dead; this does not mean that I am capable of putting the cat in some superposition. A superposition is not an "or"; an "or" is usually a description of an uncertainty from some point of view, and this is not superposition.

The cat is in a state of being both alive and dead at the same time
until Schrödinger checks to see

No, this is not what superposition is about. Nothing can be both dead and alive.

Of course the interesting thing here is exactly which or whose reality
changes

It might not be true that any reality would change. Some interpretations of quantum mechanics, that postulate the collapse of the wave function might argue that reality has suddenly changed after the measurement, but many-worlds interpretations might argue that reality has not changed, just evolved.
As for the question about nested boxes, as suggested in the comments, this is well-known and is called the Wigner's friend problem. It even has its own wiki page. The answer you are looking for might be on the page, but depends on your favorite interpretation.

Yes, it's all analogy for things that are happening at a quantum level.
"don't make reality".. they kind of do. Before the wave function collapses, the reality of the outcome does not exist. Nor in fact will it exist, until you actually do the observation. The act of observation collapses the wave function.
Which I know again, is analogy.. what does collapsing a wave function even really mean in terms of the physical world and outside the realms of mathematics.

I don’t like the sentence « the reality of the outcome does not exist ». I prefer « something exists, that awaits for observation to become an outcome ».

Eu penso que que a questão do gato é um fato. Acredito que ele estava se referindo a uma formaçao de materia decomposta, as moleculas na caixa podem sofrer um aumento de pressão e com isso tb volume, se agrupando novamente e recriando a vida. A historia q eu conheci, tinha junto da caixa tb uma maçá. Depois de muitos poderia ser possivel que tanto o gato quanto a maça recobrassem seus estados naturais.. eu nao sou fisico nem matematico, mas acredito que ele tava mais pro lado da criogenia.

English is the preferred language on most of Stack Exchange. Machine translation without comment: "I think the cat thing is a fact. I believe he was referring to a formation of decomposed matter, the molecules in the box can suffer an increase in pressure and with that also in volume, grouping together again and recreating life. The story I know, there was also an apple next to the box. After many years it could be possible that both the cat and the apple recovered their natural states. I am not a physicist or mathematician, but I believe he was more on the cryogenics side."

Physics paradoxes illustrate the ways that physicists have a tendency to make practical or cognitive errors when describing a certain category of systems using a certain model. They do this by describing a physical system and either appearing to obtain an unphysical conclusion, or obtaining a conclusion which appears to be unphysical.
I already wrote most of the answer needed to explain these errors here: What is a system?. I'm pasting it here, because the background matters and I don't feel like retyping everything from scratch. If you've already read it, skip to the last section.

The model of a system is a mathematical object which can be mathematically defined. It is the ordered set of interacting mathematical objects and the rules by which they interact.
The system is the part of reality thus modeled, and has no mathematical definition except for the fact that it is thus modeled. You can trip over your cat, you cannot trip over a mathematical object that represents your cat.

The component definitions of a mathematical model of a system are:

Simplifying assumptions and equations of state. I have grouped these together because they're the same mathematical objects.


The topological space. (Which includes rules for determining relative positions and orientations, if applicable.)
The complete list of mathematical objects that aren't the elements of the topological space, but whose position or distribution is associated with the elements of the topological space; and their associated rules for their relationships to other elements in the system.
The complete list of variables that are elements of each mathematical object and their rules for their relationships to other elements of the mathematical object. (For instance, in classical physics, an object's mass is that variable which is inversely proportional to the second time derivative of the position vector associated with a particular object.)


Boundary conditions. How are we initializing all of our state variables?
Domain. What are the rules for where our model is physically meaningful? This could be as simple as a start and end value for the time variable or as weird as "between observation events".
Observables. What do you do to the whole mathematical object to make it output a prediction of a particular measurement?


Notably, a model embeds a system in the universe and handles your need-to-account's by defining the whole universe. For example, if you need to account for mass transfer across the boundary, you just add a "mass transfer across the boundary" object to the universe. In a rare convergence of consistent terminology, this makes the model of a system a mathematical universe, which is where you'll find a formal definition in terms of set theory.
The system's domain is the domain in which the person doing the modeling hopes that that definition of the universe is an adequate approximation as regards predicting measurements. Its rules for observables incorporate what the person doing the modeling hopes adequately accounts for the fact that in defining the universe, she has pretended that she doesn't exist - but she still needs to make predictions.
Practical errors enter via:

Simplifying assumptions about the universe that turn out to be false.
Boundary conditions based on false or irrelevant measurements.
Nonphysical equations of state (bad physics / biology / whatever).
Incorrect guess about the domain of relevance.
Incorrect choice of observable operators.

Cognitive errors confuse results via:

Mistaking state variables for measurement predictions without the intercession of observable operators.
Mistaking the model for the system.
Mistaking what you've actually predicted for what you'd like to be able to predict. (Or just lying about it: P-hacking, etc.)
Forgetting that we had to pretend that we didn't exist when we made the model, but actually we do exist.


The Cat Experiment illustrates the following mistakes:

Nonphysical equations of state: isolation is nonphysical, especially for interactions of macroscopic objects like cats and physicists. The only way to actually isolate a system is to put it infinitely far away. This is also a case of forgetting that we had to pretend that we didn't exist when we made the model, but actually we do exist.

Mistaking the model for the system: the state function that can be interpreted to give information about measurements of the cat is indeed a superposition of eigenstates. But you cannot trip over an eigenstate. This is the big one. 3 and 4 are extensions of this mistake.

Mistaking state variables for measurement predictions. Most classical physics state functions have a trivial 1:1 mapping to its observables: observable operators just take a state variable out of the system and output its value at the designated coordinates as a measurement prediction. QM is different: observable operators apply a sequence of operations to the state function and output a value that wasn't anywhere to be found in any of the state variables. Experience of classical mathematical physics (even primary school physics, like questions about travel times or numbers of apples) makes us expect state functions to be, or be made of, mathematical objects with 1:1 mapping to individual intrinsic physical meanings. In QM they just aren't.

Mistaking what you've actually predicted for what you'd like to be able to predict. QM stochastically predicts the characteristics of measurement events and that's it. Physicists and philosophers would really, really like QM to describe the metaphysical character of reality between measurement events, but the only such description you can dig out of it is a self-referential one: reality has such character as to comport with the predictions.


The truth value associated with the Cat Experiment is that physicists tend to make these mistakes about QM. Any speculation about meaning of its claims about cats in boxes misses the point: a properly formulated Cat Experiment without the above mistakes just outputs boring facts about what you're likely to measure and how likely you are to measure it.

If the model doesn’t actually describe reality, it’s only useful in an instrumental way, not as an actual theory of reality. And no, science isn’t just about mathematical models. It’s about creating models and posits that give a full picture of reality. It’s about explanation. In other words, traditional QM is incomplete, which is why the Copenhagen interpretation is criticized. Calling anyone who points this out mistaken is nothing but a mistake on your part instead.

Science never claims to have a complete theory. It just has ones that are useful in a given domain ((which may be very large), haven't been refuted, and are considered plausible. Incompleteness is a flaw to be addressed, but does not refute the model as a counterexample might. Yes QM is incomplete; and unintuitive, and frustrating. Unfortunately nobody has come up with a model that works as well and it's simpler. Gods know people are still trying. They may. Until they succeed, QM is what we've got. The universe made no promises that it would be easy to understand.

@keshlam If that comment is meant for Syed, it's missing an @. If it's meant for me, I agree, but you're going to have to explain what relevance it's supposed to have if you want me to take any meaning from it.

It was indeed a response to Syed's comment. It is premature to label as mistaken any model which produces correct results as often as the competing models do. And correcting the mistake may turn out to only be a minor tweak. Or it may turn out to have been decades of wasted effort. String theory is pretty, but so far has failed to propose any test that can distinguish it from other cases; it may be brilliant, or it may turn out to have been a distraction, and hopefully we will eventually figure out which but until then all we can say is that it is not provably wrong. Ditto Copenhagen.

@keshlam All I said was that the Copenhagen interpretation of QM is incomplete. And you agreed. Where did I say it’s mistaken? The only thing premature is your understanding and willingness to jump to conclusions
